# Replacing variable containing single apostrophes with double apostrophe in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm inputting variables from an array in a foreach loop into a database. Sometimes, these variables have an apostrophe in them. I know I need them to look like this as they get inserted:

```
("INSERT INTO table (lastname) VALUES('O''Brien')")
```

I need something along the lines of:

```
str_replace("'","''","$lastname"); //  $lastname happens to equal O'Brien
```

But the single quotes end up making it think that the room in between is a string. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `$str = addslashes($str);`

Comment: Use proper escaping like mysql(i)_real_escape_string or use prepared statements.

Comment: addslashes?!?! you kidding?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using *mysqli* (because nobody would be using *mysql*, right), you should prepare a statement once, bind parameters then execute it in your loop.

Here's a basic example...

```
// assuming $con is a valid mysqli instance

$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `table` (lastname) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $lastName);

// assuming you have a collection of last names in $names
foreach ($names as $lastName) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```